# QTableWidget добавление строк с данными

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton, qtablewidget, qlineedit

Есть три поля `QLineEdit`: **`x`**, **`y`**, **`z`**. 
Хочу при нажатии на кнопку, заполненные поля попадали в таблицу `QTableWidget`, а поля очищались для нового ввода.

После нового ввода и нажатии повторно кнопки, должна добавится строка с новыми данными и как потом получить определенные данные в определенной строке?

```py
import sys
import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget
from mywindow import Ui_MainWindow


class RC(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
                super(RC, self).__init__()
                self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
                self.ui.setupUi(self)
                self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
                self.setWindowTitle('Подбор')
                self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.table)


        def table(self):
                # Retrieve text from QLineEdit
                x = self.ui.x.text()
                y = self.ui.y.text()
                z = self.ui.z.text()

                self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
                # # Add text to the row
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(x))
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(y))
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(z))
                

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = RC()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
#import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QLineEdit
#from mywindow import Ui_MainWindow      ???????????????????????????????


class RC(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RC, self).__init__()
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)                                    # +++
        
        self.lineEdit_x = QLineEdit(placeholderText="введите: x")
        self.lineEdit_y = QLineEdit(placeholderText="введите: y")
        self.lineEdit_z = QLineEdit(placeholderText="введите: z")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit_x, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit_y, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit_z, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 3)        

    def add_row(self):
        x = self.lineEdit_x.text()
        y = self.lineEdit_y.text()
        z = self.lineEdit_z.text()

        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()                               # +++
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)                                 # +++

        # # Add text to the row  vvvvvvvvvvv
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(x)) # rowPosition
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(y))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(z))
        
        self.lineEdit_x.clear()                                                 # +++
        self.lineEdit_y.clear()
        self.lineEdit_z.clear()
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = RC()
    w.setWindowTitle('Подбор')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня форма сделана в qt designer и from mywindow import Ui_MainWindow подключает мою форму.

Comment: @Andrey я рад за вас, что у вас есть форма. Но почему вы ее не опубликовали ?

Comment: я только учусь))) спасибо большое, на основании вашего кода все сделал!

Comment: @Andrey пожалуйста